# How to configure Clion to work with SDL2?

Tags: c++, c++11, sdl, sdl-2, clion

I´m just trying to learn how to use SDL in Clion (the Jetbrains IDE), i found an answer in a post to edit my CMakeLists.txt, i did it!! but it didn´t worked.

I can use the libraries but I can´t compile it, in the image you can see the error in the output console.

Can somebody help me to configure it, please

This is my "CMakeLists.txt"

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(OpenGLTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -lmingw32")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(OpenGLTest ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(OpenGLTest libSDL2main libSDL2 libSDL2_test)
```

And this is my "main.cpp"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

int main() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

PS: This is the code that I wrote is just to test the compiling.

This is the error in Clion console

[image]

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szil0.png)

Comment: What kind of an error message did you get?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szil0.png                                                              this is the output console

Comment: and here you can see my files and libraries https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiE8X.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct text of "CMakeLists.txt" is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(OpenGLTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -lmingw32")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(OpenGLTest ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(OpenGLTest mingw32 SDL2main SDL2)
```

And you have to copy the file "SDL2.dll" (located in \bin) to the "cmake-build-debug" folder. Here is an example https://gyazo.com/fae7ab9ccc73e3a66e9d9c2d3419ff1e

PS: Don´t forget the "include" and "lib" folders

This is an example code just to test it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv []) {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) {
        std::cout << "SDL_Init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    } 
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, but I think you should remove the `lib` before every link lib: `target_link_libraries(OpenGLTest SDL2main SDL2 SDL2_test)`

(the error message said cannot find `-llibSDL2main` which the correct flag should be `-lSDL2main`)

Comment: What is the error message this time? I think you don't need `SDL2_test`, and bring `mingw32` down: target_link_libraries(OpenGLTest mingw32 SDL2main SDL2)`

Comment: is this, i changed to target_link_libraries(OpenGLTest mingw32 SDL2main SDL2) https://gyazo.com/06b897f383eed83ddfffe53612d25614

Comment: You need to declare main as `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`

Comment: I don´s see any error in console i just see that: 
Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)

Comment: but it seems better

Comment: During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Can I see your `main.cpp`?

Find `SDL2.dll` in `SDL2-2.0.5\bin` folder then place it in the same folder with your exe file (or your project folder)

Comment: https://gyazo.com/d17380197661695ee2878c559a368b78                              This is my main.cpp and my files with the SDL2.dll, and i have the same output

Comment: try putting `SDL_Quit();` at the end (before `return 0;`). Also check the return value of `SDL_Init`:

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "SDL_Init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

Comment: same result :c https://gyazo.com/3fdf9403e5dd79d98acf272f8a7f5c2f            You think I have to configure something here? https://gyazo.com/4e6cab2b0538633fea05beed090fd772

Comment: try copy `SDL2.dll` to `cmake-build-debug`, or open `OpenGLTest.exe` manually to see if you're missing any .dll

Comment: It worked!! I will answer this question with your help, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

1. copy SDL2.dll (located in x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin) to the C:\Windows\System32 folder to be the permanent solution and the then restart your OS.
2. don't forget to add the following in your CMakeLists.txt

   - set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -lmingw32")
     set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")

Answer (score 0):

I had the following configuration file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(vector_fields_simulations)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

include_directories(.)
include_directories(src)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(vector_fields_simulations src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
```

and **the only thing I needed to do was to change** `SLD2/SDL.h` **by** `../SLD2/SDL.h`

Note 1: I'm using [FindSDL2.cmake](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brendan-w/collector/master/cmake/FindSDL2.cmake) (github link) inside a folder called cmake so that the project includes SDL, the latter isn't mandatory but it may help you.

Note 2: If your program throws an error in compilation, try to use `#undef main` before the `main` function in your `.cpp` main file or change it by `main(int argv, char** args)`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to fuss with make files. This is my entire project. There's a bug in the SDL download from the website at time of writing so I installed via homebrew and that one was without the bug.

You can also build and run the executable

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -e

INCLUDES="-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2/2.28.2/include/"
LIBS="-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2/2.28.2/lib/ -lSDL2"

gcc -o peanut main.c ${INCLUDES} ${LIBS}
```

[image]